# drag SVG element to a new location

Tags: javascript, svg

```
           if (action == "mousedown") {
                startx = x;
                starty = y;
            }

            if (action == "mousemove") {
                if (!mouseisdown) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    //console.log(target);
                    var transformX = x - startx;
                    var transformY = y - starty;
                    //                console.log(x, y, startx, starty);
                    var transformAttr = 'translate(' + transformX + ',' + transformY + ')';
                    test.setAttribute('transform', transformAttr);
                }
            }

            if (action == "mouseup") {
                var transformX = x - startx;
                var transformY = y - starty;
                //                console.log(x, y, startx, starty);
                var transformAttr = 'translate(' + transformX + ',' + transformY + ')';
                test.setAttribute('transform', transformAttr);
            }
```

Below is my way to get x, y position:

```
            $("svg").on("mousedown", function (event) {
              mouseisdown = true;
              var offset = $("#center").offset();  //#center is the canvas
              var x = event.pageX - offset.left;
              var y = event.pageY - offset.top;                
              current_tool("mousedown", x, y, null);
            });
```

Above is part of my code, my problem is this function works well on the first move, but when I tried to move it second time, the element object will suddenly back to its origin location before this first move, How to fix that problem? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not updating x and y in your code. just update with new coordinates

Comment: @kpsingh you mean I need to update the cx and cy for ellipse, x, y for rect? Because I need to move group of element also, update the x, y seems not work for the g element....

Comment: where is it you're getting the current values of the transform attribute's translation?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I have updated the part.

Comment: So the problem is as I stated. You're not getting the current transform attribute's translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if (action == "mousedown") {
                startx = x - test.transform.animVal["0"].matrix.e;  //change
                starty = y - test.transform.animVal["0"].matrix.f;  // change2
            }

            if (action == "mousemove") {
                if (!mouseisdown) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (test.transform.animVal["0"]) {
                        console.log(test.transform.animVal["0"].matrix);
                        var transformX = x - startx;
                        var transformY = y - starty;
                        var transformAttr = 'translate(' + transformX + ',' + transformY + ')';
                        test.setAttribute('transform', transformAttr);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (action == "mouseup") {
                var transformX = x - startx;
                var transformY = y - starty;
                //                console.log(x, y, startx, starty);
                var transformAttr = 'translate(' + transformX + ',' + transformY + ')';
                test.setAttribute('transform', transformAttr);
            }
```

Problem solved by myself, the reason of the problem is that, when I tries the second move, the start position did not take the first transform into consider, so after the change the code in "mousedown" handler, the problem settled.